# Permanently change the units in Google Maps (from miles to km)

Tags: google-maps

Despite all the tracking that Google does, it somehow can't remember that I prefer to use km as a unit on Google Maps. Every time I need to click on the label to toggle it from Miles to Km.

Is there any way to change this preference permanently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to change the preference permanently at this time.

Comment: That's very unfortunate 